# ObjectBox: Unique/Index across multiple properties

Tags: android, objectbox

Is there any way to get multi-property Unique or Index in ObjectBox? For example, if I want a person to be unique or indexed based on their full name, so that there could be more than one John or more than one Smith, but there can only be one John Smith?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not supported at the moment and there are no plan in the near future to support this. Of course, you could have two separate indexes, and have that logic on your end.

Comment: Hey @markus-junginger .How about now?Is it possible to make multiple fields unique?